# Compare data from API response to oracle table

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, hibernate

I have an internal table that needs to be maintained and kept in sync with an external table which I can only access via a rest API. After getting the API data if the internal table doesn’t contain a row for the unique identifier I insert a row. If it exists but something has changed I do an update. And if the internal table has a row that is no longer in the response data I delete it. My initial thought is build a temp table containing all the rest data and then do an insert where not exists, update where different, and delete from master where not in temp. Drop temp table at the end. The core app is Java spring boot data JPA so that’s what I’m using. Is there a cleaner way to do this? The data set isn’t expected to be huge. Less than 1200 rows expected.

I have a model class and had also thought about just comparing the objects from db and the rest data but not sure if that’s a better approach or something different.

Comment: You can create a rest client library to retrieve the data from the external table via, iterate through the external data and compare it with the internal data to determine which rows need to be inserted, updated, or deleted.

Comment: If you have only 1200 items, consider using a data structure inside your app, like List<ModelClass>. Well, it depends on data you have, if it is a 2Gb BLOB in one cell, then, you know :)...  Other solution can be a in memory NoSQL DB, like Redis to store API responses.